# GCP VMs OS Patch Notification

Tags: google-cloud-platform

How to setup alert for OS patches once OS Patches are available for a particular OS and related VMs. I would like to receive a mail from GCP mentioning your instance has important security patches available. The alert will be fired based on patching status in OS Patch Management console which states Important Security Patches available for VM. I tried as per instruction from below documentation but inevntories or vulnerability-report tags throwing Error.

https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/compute/os-config/inventories/list

Comment: If there is an error message, read the message, make an effort to understand what it is telling you and include it in the question where you are asking others to diagnose the problem. Also if the error is about permissions, read the last paragraph of the doc you linked.

Comment: What's your current error?

Comment: For almost all of the major operating systems, multiple patches are released every day. You will quickly burn out with the high noise level from emails. Patches should be applied only after testing/verifying their impact.

Answer (score 0):

My request is clear and not related to the existing integration issue.

In GCP, whenever patches available to any of my VM, I would like to receive a notification which would enable me to manually trigger patches for the VM. The query is about notification about the availability of the patches of the vms. Probably a feature request to GCP post seeking help in various platforms